# iFrame Refresh and some design ?'s

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf, iframe

I am learning Web Applications with Microsoft.NET Framework 4. While going through the book I am coding a prototype of a website my company wants. My company sells reports to clients. They want to have a website that, when a customer logs in, they can view all the reports purchased (no store as of now).

My design is:
- A database table that contains multiple usernames, report names, and a filepaths to the reports.
- A file store that the server will have access to that contains the actual files (PDFs). 
- A website that after the user logs in will query the database, get all the rows of reports belonging to the user, list them, and have a click event that will change an iframes src to the filepath of the report that was selected.

I have most of it working. I have the database query working, the reports icons being populated based on the what was queried, and the click event changing the src attribute of the iFrame to the filepath.

What I don't have working is, I can't get the iFrame to show the report. If I have a report in a folder contained in the wesite and have it hard coded it displays fine. If I change the hardcoded value to `U:\\somefolder\someusername\somereport1.pdf` it won't display (U: is a mapped drive). And it definitely doesn't work when I change the source to `U:\\somefolder\someusername\somereport2.pdf` based on clicking the report icon.

Is this a sound design? It seems I am so close to having it working. 
Will the iFrame automatically refresh when the src attribute is changed?

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
Leon

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know what you are referring too. Can you clarify?

Comment: I do not think that the iframe can show a file for security reasons. Why not you direct give the pdf using url ?

Comment: Aristos, sorry for ignorance. I am very new. The PDFs won't be stored on the site, they will be stored in a file system that the web server has access too. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Raminson, the other 2 questions have not been answered correctly for me. I had to use a very ugly tree traversal to get the filepath from the custom control. I have comments asking for further help. Thanks for looking out for me though :)

Comment: you still need to place the url and not the file path. You can use a  handler that can read them from u:\\ and send to the user.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `src` of the iframe you're telling the browser to go fetch whatever is at that URL. Since the browser does not have access to the file store, only the web server, it cannot download the file. If you use your browsers developer tools to watch network traffic, you'll see a 404 being returned each time you update the iframe.

The browser either needs direct access to the location of the PDFs, although this has no security, or the website has to proxy them allowing it to check for user permissions first.

Comment: thanks for the input roryf :)
can you point me to some material on how the website can use a proxy like this? I am very new and this seems to be pretty advanced :)